# How to write a type signature with two parameters?

Tags: agda

I try to learn agda and use the [tutorial](https://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Sets.Parametric.html#1).
I paste code for two mutally recursive sets

```
module MoreSets where 

data List₁ (A B : Set) : Set
data List₂ (A B : Set) : Set

data List₁ (A B : Set) where
  []  :                 List₁ A B
  _∷_ : A → List₂ A B → List₁ A B

data List₂ (A B : Set) where
  _∷_ : B → List₁ A B → List₂ A B
```

and get the error

```
MoreSets.agda:6,12-23
Unexpected type signature for parameters A B
when checking the definition of List₁
```

I assume a trivial error but cannot see it.

What is a simple tutorial to learn agda for a Haskell programmer which does not go deep into category theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to repeat the type annotations that you had
in the declarations when you're defining the inductive type. So:

```
module MoreSets where

data List₁ (A B : Set) : Set
data List₂ (A B : Set) : Set

data List₁ A B where
  []  :                 List₁ A B
  _∷_ : A → List₂ A B → List₁ A B

data List₂ A B where
  _∷_ : B → List₁ A B → List₂ A B
```

Comment: I understand that the error is due to the tutorial I follow is out of date by several years. Is there a (not too mathematical theory heavy) text to learn agda?